# Why can we use present simple for "I feel fine"?

Tags: present-tense, continuous-aspect

“I feel fine this morning”, why? He feels fine all morning, it means that this action takes a long time, so we must use present continuous.

[image]

> 4. I **feel** fine this morning, but I **was** very tired last night.

If both variants are right, please, share the rules about present simple in this case.

Comment: You could equally well say 'I am feeling fine this morning'. I suppose the speaker means that he feels fine at the present moment, but adds '...this morning' because he goes on to make a comparison with how he felt last night. There is no rule, but both versions are acceptable.

Comment: Thanks!!<3 Do you mean “present moment” something which is not continuous? Present moment=fleeting moment?

Comment: By _at the present moment_ I just meant _now_! Obviously the 'feeling fine' is a continuing state, but an English speaker is just as likely to say 'I feel fine' without any difference in meaning. See Shoe's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Both *I feel fine* and *I'm feeling fine* are grammatical (although this [nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m+feeling+fine%2CI+feel+fine&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27m%20feeling%20fine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20feel%20fine%3B%2Cc0) shows the former is a lot more common than the latter).

Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p455) in *'Present tenses: Advanced points - section 7:  I feel / I'm feeling'* says:

> Verbs that refer to physical feelings (e.g. *feel, hurt, ache*) can
> often be used in simple or progressive tenses without much difference
> of meaning.
>
> - How do you feel? OR How are you feeling?
> - My head aches. OR > My head is aching.

Comment: Impressive find (or memory).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. Swan can usually be relied on to have something clear and concise about such simple grammatical issues.